# Configure MongoDB write concern timeout?

Tags: java, mongodb

How to configure write concern on mongoDB client with time.

I am using mongoDB client with replica acknowledged.I want to configure write concern with wtimeout.I am using Java driver.

```
mongoClient.setWriteConcern(WriteConcern.REPLICA_ACKNOWLEDGED.continueOnError(true));
```

How to configure it with wtimeout??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the API ([Link](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.10.1/com/mongodb/WriteConcern.html#WriteConcern(int,%20int)))it seems that you can use following constructor to initialize `WriteConcern` and use the same instead of `WriteConcern.REPLICA_ACKNOWLEDGED.continueOnError(true)`

```
mongoClient.setWriteConcern(new WriteConcern(0, 10));
```